# Stacking vertical on page flexible width/height images

Tags: css

So, after 30 minutes of trying everything out, I can't seem to get these two div's to sit right next to each other inline.  I must be missing something for sure.

The two images in the .shirt-box box are a simple jquery fade to color transition.  But the two divs won't sit alongside each other.  This is for a reponsive layout when the viewport dips below 1100px.  So I'm using percentages...

HTML Code:

```
<div class="shirtbar">
    <div class="shirt-box">
        <a href="#"><img class="before" src="img/shirts/shirt1-overlay.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="after" src="img/shirts/shirt1.jpg" /></a>
    </div><!-- shirt-box -->
    <div class="shirt-box">
        <a href="#"><img class="before" src="img/shirts/shirt1-overlay.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="after" src="img/shirts/shirt1.jpg" /></a>
    </div><!-- shirt-box -->
</div><!-- shirtbar -->
```

And the CSS:

```
.shirtbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
.shirt-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
.shirt-box img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.shirt-box img.before {
    height: 309px;
    width: 215px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
.shirt-box img.after {
    height: 309px;
    width: 215px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're aiming before but I've created a fiddle that the displays to images next to each other if there's enough space and otherwise below each other if not. http://jsfiddle.net/TgjHU/. Is this going in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Totally Revamped Answer

I assumed from your question that you wanted the `before` and `after` "stacked" by `z-index` one on top of another. But it appears you really want them stacked vertically on the page. That does not even require absolute positioning (unless you need them so for some other reason).

[Here is the new answer](http://jsfiddle.net/YEKg9/20/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="shirtbar">
    <div class="shirt-box">
        <a href="#" class="before"><img  src="http://dummyimage.com/215x309/000/fff.png&text=Scaling+image" /></a>
        <a href="#" class="after"><img  src="http://dummyimage.com/215x309/f00/fff.png&text=Scaling+image" /></a>
    </div><!-- shirt-box -->
    <div class="shirt-box">
        <a href="#" class="before"><img  src="http://dummyimage.com/215x309/0f0/fff.png&text=Scaling+image" /></a>
        <a href="#" class="after"><img  src="http://dummyimage.com/215x309/00f/fff.png&text=Scaling+image" /></a>
    </div><!-- shirt-box -->
</div><!-- shirtbar -->
```

**CSS**

```
.shirtbar {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    /* uncomment below if you want 
       shirtbar to actually visually wrap shirt-box */
    /* overflow: auto; */
}
.shirt-box {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.shirt-box a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 0;
    text-decoration: none;    
}

.shirt-box img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The second one works, but the right image rolls over the first one, I want them both to scale, not overwrite each other.  I think I can figure that one out...

Comment: Ok, so I got it half way there.  I added a second row of image divs but they are positioning themselves at the bottom of the previous two.    That 309px height is still in effect preventing it, I've tried a few combinations but I can't get it to scale to the size of the images?  [http://jsfiddle.net/telagraphic/2HPmu/](http://jsfiddle.net/telagraphic/2HPmu/)

Comment: Click this link instead and then resize smaller and you'll see the scaling screw up I'm talking about.  [http://jsfiddle.net/telagraphic/2HPmu/](http://jsfiddle.net/telagraphic/2HPmu/)

Comment: @nick--do you want the images to always be 215px x 309px? Or to scale with the page?

Comment: @nick--okay, I think I understand what you were going for better now, and have revamped the answer.